# visual studio 2010 don't want open new project (application wizard open in internet browser)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

My c++ visual 2010 don't want open new project, every time when I put name of the project and click OK button after that it open my internet browser instead of  Win32 Application Wizard. For better demonstration i record my steps here :
http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=iqxzk4&s=7

Answer (score 0):

Try the solutions in this thread - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/40fde5ae-a179-42af-91f6-e2c488b5375f

Comment: After some searching I have found one other possible solution to this problem - http://theintrospector.blogspot.com/2008/10/navigation-to-web-page-was-cancelled.html  I hope this works for you.

Comment: thnx ... again man I really grateful to you search, but unfortunaly nothing is changed, I think that the problem is deeper,...